# Are there any unitary matrices which satisfy the Yang-Baxter equation which are universal for quantum computation?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, braid-groups, cryptography, quantum-computation

Let $H$ be a finite dimensional hilbert space. Let $L:H\otimes H\rightarrow H\otimes H$ be a unitary transformation. Then the equation
$$(L\otimes I)(I\otimes L)(L\otimes I)=(I\otimes L)(L\otimes I)(I\otimes L)$$
where $I:H\rightarrow H$ is the identity mapping is known as the Yang-Baxter equation.

We shall call a linear transformation $L:H\otimes H\rightarrow H\otimes H$ a universal quantum gate if there is some $n$ such that the unitary transformations of the form
$I^{\otimes i}\otimes L\otimes I^{\otimes (n-i-2)}$
along with the mappings $\lambda\cdot I^{\otimes n}$ where $|\lambda|=1$ generate a dense subgroup of the unitary group $U(2^{n})$.

Does there exist a universal quantum gate $L:H\otimes H\rightarrow H\otimes H$ which satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation? If so, then what is the least natural number $n$ so that there is a universal quantum gate $L:\mathbb{C}^{n}\otimes\mathbb{C}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}\otimes\mathbb{C}^{n}$ which satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation?

$\textbf{Motivation}$

If $L$ is a quantum gate which satisfies the Yang-Baxter equation, then for all $n$, the function $\phi:B_{n}\rightarrow H^{\oplus n}$ defined by
$\phi(\sigma_{i})=I^{\oplus(i-1)}\oplus L\oplus I^{\oplus(n-i-1)}$ is a group homomorphism where $B_{n}$ denotes the $n$-strand braid group.

If $L$ is also universal, then any quantum algorithm (called algorithm A) can be emulated by a unitary transformation $\phi(w)$ for some braid word $w$. However, if
$\sigma_{i_{1}}^{e_{1}}...\sigma_{i_{n}}^{e_{n}}$ is one of the normal forms for the braid for $w$, then the sequence of quantum gates
$(\phi(\sigma_{i_{1}})^{e_{1}},...,\phi(\sigma_{i_{n}})^{e_{n}})$ obfuscates the original quantum algorithm so that a person cannot figure out how algorithm A works simply by looking at the braid $\sigma_{i_{1}}^{e_{1}}...\sigma_{i_{n}}^{e_{n}}$.

The idea of using braid group representations to obfuscate quantum algorithms has been proposed in [this recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6458) where they have observed that the Fibonacci representation of braid groups could be used to obfuscate quantum algorithms. However, a universal unitary transformation that satisfies the Yang-Baxter transformation seems to be a more direct way of using braids to obfuscate quantum algorithms.

Comment: Carlo Beenakker's references show that there is most likely no universal Yang-Baxter unitary operator in the qubit case when $H$ is a 2-dimensional complex Hilbert space. It is unknown whether a universal Yang-Baxter unitary operator exists on a higher dimensional Hilbert space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Braiding Operators are Universal Quantum Gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0401090), by Louis Kauffman and Samuel Lomonaco (2004)

> In this paper, we prove that certain solutions to the Yang-Baxter equation together with local unitary two-dimensional operators form a universal set of quantum gates. In particular, we show that a single specific solution of the Yang-Baxter Equation, the Bell basis change matrix, is a universal gate.

If we wish to do away with the local unitaries, and only use unitary solutions of the Yang-Baxter equation, then universal quantum computation is not known to be possible, because a classical simulation is available, see [Classical simulation of Yang-Baxter gates](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.1361) (2004).

Comment: In that paper, they show that the local unitary operators (all one qubit operators) along with the Yang-Baxter unitary operator give you universal quantum computation (the one qubit maps get in the way of obfuscating quantum algorithms). I am wondering if we can get universal quantum computation using the Yang-Baxter unitary operator alone.

Comment: that is not known to be possible.